# Installing Bootstrap in NAS server?

Tags: terminal, nas

I have a Synology NAS Server, and am trying to follow these instructions to install Boostrap:
http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc#Installing_compiled.2Fbinary_programs_using_ipkg

I got to this so far:

```
nas> sh syno-x07-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
Optware Bootstrap for syno-x07.
Extracting archive... please wait
bootstrap/
bootstrap/bootstrap.sh
bootstrap/ipkg-opt.ipk
bootstrap/ipkg.sh
bootstrap/optware-bootstrap.ipk
bootstrap/wget.ipk
1226+1 records in
1226+1 records out
Backup your configuration settings, then type:
  rm -rf /volume1/@optware
  rm -rf /usr/lib/ipkg
This will remove all existing optware packages.

You must *reboot* and then restart the bootstrap script.


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2012-05-10 02:27:56 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

nas> rm syno-x07-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
rm: can't remove 'syno-x07-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh': No such file or directory
nas> Connection to 192.168.0.124 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.0.124 closed.
macpro:~ monster$ ssh root@192.168.0.124
root@192.168.0.124's password: 


BusyBox v1.16.1 (2012-05-10 02:27:56 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

nas> ipkg update
-ash: ipkg: not found
```

I am not sure what to do about this error.  Does anyone have any ideas?  It looks like ipkg is *kind* of installed, but after rebooting the NAS server it basically disappears...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=23246#p140224

1. I deleted @optware - "rm -rf /volume1/@optware"
2. I deleted ipkg - "rm -rf /usr/lib/ipkg"
3. I deleted bootstrap: "rm -rf /volume1/bootstrap"
4. I deleted syno-x07-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh - "rm -rf /volume1/syno-x07-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh"
5. Checked my NAS's CPU here: http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_kind_of_CPU_does_my_NAS_have and found out I have a "Marvell Kirkwood mv6281" -> meaning I need to download  http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh

Followed instructions on that post (linked above).